# App saves to SD card, phone has no SD card slot!

Tags: sd-card, stock-android

I am currently using to JBTimer app to time Rubik's Cube solves on my Droid Maxx, and wanted to export the data to do some analysis. The app has a few built-in options for exporting, but every single one of them will only export to an SD card which, if you've ever used a Droid Maxx before, you'll know there isn't a slot for in the phone. The app doesn't give any errors or anything, but I can't find the data on my phone when I connect it to my computer. I would really rather not type 300-something numbers into an Excel spreadsheet manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Rob is right. Android is very well designed. You *have* a SD card that is the memory of your device. If you'd have a SD Slot then you'd have 2 SD Cards. Why this happens? Because it's assumed that Android needs a place where to save pictures, savegames, etc and it has a special partition for each: SD (yes, it's emulated), applications, system files, etc.

This is why when you do a full reset on the device those files are not deleted! Because it's not necessary! Only system files and folders are touched in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides SD Card emulation for devices that don't have one as well as a pointer to a physical one if available. If you use ES File Explorer on your device (I highly recommend that app!), you will be able to go to **/mnt/extSdCard**.
No root required, it is only a pointer (you can see the black curved arrow over the folder icon). You will be able to find your saves in there.
It is possible that **extSdCard** has another name: Sdcard2, etc.[image]